# XCode 8 moving elements size and position in layout

Tags: layout, storyboard, position, size, xcode8

I disable Auto Layout and Trait Variations cause I want to fix my Objects, having lot of buttos in the storyboard. But the problem now, with XCode 8, is the layout elements are moving automatically randomly! Only few points, but never keeps the layout in the position or size I set. I'm loosing lot of time trying to keep my storyboard in order.

Please ... anyone knows how to solve it?